# Bootstrap Form Layout isn't presenting correctly

Tags: php, html

I have created a form with tabs that submits to a MySQL database.
I am using bootstrap to create the tabs and the forms. But I am struggling with the alignment of the form inputs. In my previous code I had the layout working perfectly. But since I added the Tabs this does not work.

Photo of Expected result and what i currently have (photo1:please ignore the section after the first hr tags) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkYqr.jpg

What i have tried - https://pastebin.com/crS9v86N
I have also tried adding in a control-group class and this didnt work either

```html
<form class="row g-3" action="<?= $data['action'] ?>" method="post">

  <?php if(isset($data['record']['id'])): ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $data['record']['id'] ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if(isset($data['currentPage'])): ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?= $data['currentPage'] ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if(isset($data['hash'])): ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?= $data['hash'] ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <!--Using a list to create the tabs -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#contact-tab" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab">Contact Details</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#questions-tab" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Questions</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#delivery-tab" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Delivery Info</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <!-- This involves the tav content -->
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contact-tab">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <label for="site_name" class="form-label">Site Name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site_name" name="site_name" value="<?= $data['record']['site_name'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Site Name" required><br>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="poNum" class="form-label">PO Number*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="poNum" name="poNum" value="<?= $data['record']['poNum'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Enter PO Num (Given in Email)" required>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="customer_name" class="form-label">Contact Name*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_name" name="customer_name" value="<?= $data['record']['customer_name'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Contact Name" required>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-7">
        <label for="customer_email" class="form-label">Email Address*</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="customer_email" name="customer_email" value="<?= $data['record']['customer_email'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
        <br>
      </div>

      <div class="col-4">
        <label for="customer_mobile" class="form-label">Contact Number*</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="customer_mobile" name="customer_mobile" value="<?= $data['record']['customer_mobile'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" required> <br>
      </div>

      <div class="col-8">
        <label for="street1" class="form-label">Address*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street1" name="street1" value="<?= $data['record']['street1'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Address" required>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="city" class="form-label">City/Town*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" value="<?= $data['record']['city'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="City/Town" required>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-5">
        <label for="county" class="form-label">County</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="county" name="county" value="<?= $data['record']['county'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="County">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="postcode" class="form-label">Postcode*</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" name="postcode" value="<?= $data['record']['postcode'] ?? '' ?>" placeholder="Postcode" required> <br>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Reproducible Edit

```css
.top-bar{

    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color: #006bff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.phone,.logout{
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.phone:hover,.logout:hover{
    color: #F0C330;
    transition:0.5s;
}
body{
    background-color: #A6C7F0!important;
}
.logo{
    padding:20px;
}
.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container form{    
    background-color: #EEF1F4 !important;            /*Change Size of Box*/
    width: 900px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
} 
.box{
    width: 800px;
}
.container table {
    background-color: #EEF1F4 !important;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.link-right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.suggestions{
    width:98.5%;
    height:125px;
    position: relative;
    bottom:17px;
}
.container h1{
    color: #0B2D58;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title><?= $data['title'] ?></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/create.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <?php require_once __DIR__ . '/header.phtml'; ?>
    </head> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function(e){
            console.log(e.target); // newly activated tab
            console.log(e.relatedTarget); // previous active tab
            });
        });
    </script>
    
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <form class="row g-3" action="<?= $data['action'] ?>" method="post">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">   <!--Using a list to create the tabs -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#contact-tab" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab">Contact Details</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#questions-tab" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Questions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#delivery-tab" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab">Delivery Info</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
                <div class="tab-content">       <!-- This involves the tav content -->
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contact-tab">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <label for="site_name" class="form-label">Site Name*</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="site_name"
                                    name="site_name"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['site_name'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Enter Site Name"
                                    required><br>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label for="poNum" class="form-label">PO Number*</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="poNum"
                                    name="poNum"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['poNum'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Enter PO Num (Given in Email)"
                                    required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label for="customer_name" class="form-label">Contact Name*</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="customer_name"
                                    name="customer_name"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['customer_name'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Enter Contact Name"
                                    required>
                            </div>
                    
                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                <label for="customer_email" class="form-label">Email Address*</label>
                                <input type="email"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="customer_email"
                                    name="customer_email"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['customer_email'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Enter Email"
                                    required>
                                    <br>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-4">
                                <label for="customer_mobile" class="form-label">Contact Number*</label>
                                <input type="tel"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="customer_mobile"
                                    name="customer_mobile"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['customer_mobile'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Enter Contact Number"
                                    required> <br>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-8">
                                <label for="street1" class="form-label">Address*</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="street1"
                                    name="street1"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['street1'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Address"
                                    required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label for="city" class="form-label">City/Town*</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="city"
                                    name="city"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['city'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="City/Town"
                                    required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label for="county" class="form-label">County</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="county"
                                    name="county"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['county'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="County">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label for="postcode" class="form-label">Postcode*</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="postcode"
                                    name="postcode"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['postcode'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Postcode"
                                    required> <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="questions-tab">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="current_machine">What is your Current Machine?</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="current_machine"
                                    name="current_machine"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['current_machine'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Leave blank if none"><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label for="ordered_machine">What Machine did you Order?*</label>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="ordered_machine"
                                    name="ordered_machine"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['ordered_machine'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Leave blank if none"
                                    required> <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q1">1. Are you aware of the Dimensions of the Machine(s) Ordered? 
                            <a href="img/size-reference.pdf#page=1" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> </a></h6> 
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q1">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q1']) && $data['record']['q1'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q1']) && $data['record']['q1'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q2">2. Are you aware of the Capacity of the Machine(s) Ordered? 
                            <a href="img/website-resources.pdf#page=1" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> </a></h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q2">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q2']) && $data['record']['q2'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q2']) && $data['record']['q2'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q3">3. Are you aware that the Maximum Drain Height is <i>600mm</i> up from the bottom of Machine(s)? 
                            <a href="img/website-resources.pdf#page=2" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> </a></h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q3">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q3']) && $data['record']['q3'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q3']) && $data['record']['q3'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q4">4. Are you aware of the Power Supply required for the Machine(s)?
                            <a href="img/website-resources.pdf#page=3" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> </a></h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q4">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q4']) && $data['record']['q4'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q4']) && $data['record']['q4'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q5">5. Is there a suitable Water Supply & Waste within <i>1metre</i> of the location?
                            <a href="img/website-resources.pdf#page=2" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> </a></h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q5">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q5']) && $data['record']['q5'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q5']) && $data['record']['q5'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q6">6. Is your Site located in a Hard Water area?
                            <a href="https://www.aquacure.co.uk/knowledge-base/uk-hard-water-map/" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> </a></h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q6">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q6']) && $data['record']['q6'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q6']) && $data['record']['q6'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="delivery-tab">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q7">7. What floor is the Machine(s) going to be located on?</h6>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="q7"
                                    name="q7"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['q7'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Please enter what floor your machine will be located on"> <br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q8">8. Does the Machine Require lifting over a Bar/Countertop?</h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q8">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q8']) && $data['record']['q8'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q8']) && $data['record']['q8'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q9">9. Is there clear Access to the position of the Machine(s)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp(e.g. Access through doors)</h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q9">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q9']) && $data['record']['q9'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q9']) && $data['record']['q9'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q10">10. Are you aware or do you accept that Delivery will be the day <u>before</u> Install and collection of any old machine will be the day <u>after</u> install?</h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q10">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q10']) && $data['record']['q10'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q10']) && $data['record']['q10'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q11">11. Can you accept Delivery/Install between 8am & 6pm on Weekdays?</h6>
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="q11">
                                <option selected>--Select--</option>
                                <option value="YES"<?= isset($data['record']['q11']) && $data['record']['q11'] === "YES" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Yes</option>
                                <option value="NO"<?= isset($data['record']['q11']) && $data['record']['q11'] === "NO" ? ' selected' : '' ?>>No</option>
                            </select><br><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h6 for="q12">12. Are there any Restrictions on Vehicle Size or Time restrictions in the area? (If Yes, Please Elaborate)</h6>
         https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70679936/edit#                   <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="q12"
                                    name="q12"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['q12'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Please enter any restrictions to your site"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                        <hr>
                            <h4 for="suggestions">Added Notes / Suggestions</h4>
                                <input type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    id="suggestions"
                                    name="suggestions"
                                    value="<?= $data['record']['suggestions'] ?? '' ?>"
                                    placeholder="Leave blank if none"><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you post a working example? maybe with compiled code so you/we can check what's wrong?

Comment: Yes i have edited the imgurr link which shows the issue

Comment: Photo 1 - Expected Result .Photo 2 - Current

Comment: Without code is very difficult....

Comment: I will upload the zip file.

Comment: No please read [mcve] and post your relevant compiled code using code snippet of SO

Comment: I have done the snippet. Why has this got a downvote now. I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Add div class="row" at the start of each tab and close it accordingly

```html
<div class="row">       <!-- start row here -->
                                <h1>Contact & Site Details</h1>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <label for="site_name" class="form-label">Site Name*</label>
                                    <input type="text"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        id="site_name"
                                        name="site_name"
                                        value="<?= $data['record']['site_name'] ?? '' ?>"
                                        placeholder="Enter Site Name"
                                        required><br>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label for="poNum" class="form-label">PO Number*</label>
                                    <input type="text"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        id="poNum"
                                        name="poNum"
                                        value="<?= $data['record']['poNum'] ?? '' ?>"
                                        placeholder="Enter PO Num (Given in Email)"
                                        required>
                                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).